# display social icons in a line

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I was working in this site [My Site](http://constantin-entertainment.info/pinterclass/) In the home page template i actually added the below code to social links to appear

```
<div class="ss"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none"></a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=175266875876185&amp;href=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

<g:plusone size="medium" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></g:plusone></div>
```

and added the css as follows

```
.ss iframe {
   width: 85px !important;
display:inline;
}
```

but the social icons are not coming inline.I think the twitter button is having the problem.Tried reducing the width but didn't help.Please help!! thanks!!

Comment: try to give your div height also

Comment: is it possible to mention css style for each social links ?

Comment: @user3488898 try changing your `.ss { margin: -12px 0 0 120px; display: inline; }` to `.ss { margin: 12px 0 0 0px; display: inline-block; }`

Comment: @Cheejyg : This one not showing in inline.

Comment: @Ranjith well yeah, after that add `.ss iframe.twitter-share-button, .ss iframe.twitter-tweet-button {
 width: 60px !important;
}
.ss div#___plusone_0 {
 width: 60px !important;
}`

Comment: @Cheejyg : That you not mentioned on your last comment. Because I tried yours, it doesn't make inline. :)..

Comment: @Ranjith opps, yeah I just realised it only makes the first g+ inline lol, the google plus icon is a hassle to target because there is no class applied to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is your content of the `div` width is too small. Try this one.

Change these styles,

```
.ss {
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.ss iframe { 
    /*  as it is...  */ 
}

.twitter-share-button {
  width:59px !important;
}

.gplus {
  width:59px !important;
  display:inherit !important;
}
```

Add inline style in html of

**twitter**

```
<a href="twitter" style="width: 59px !important;" > </a>
```

**facebook** 
(It may `<a> link` or `<div>` or `<iframe>`)

```
<a href="facebook" style="width: 85px !important; margin-left:8px !important;" > </a>
```

**gplus** (It may `<a> link` or `<div>` or `<iframe>`)

```
<div class="gplus">
    <a href="gplus"> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you add inline style in each social links like I mentioned above.. I seen your updated code. There you missed `!important` at last.

Comment: added that but didn help

Comment: i have added the same as above but not helping

Comment: wow .. thanks a lot .. great man great .. hoping for more answers for me